# Automatically updating csv file in sheets

Tags: excel, csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a csv file in my PC that is updating every hour. I tried to automatize the update in google sheets too.

This was the formula I used

```
=IMPORTDATA("C:\Users\octav\Documentos\Movers\RD\ALGO-USD.csv")
```

I got the error code #N/A

Is this something to be with the formula parameters? bc it ask me for the url and i´m putting the filepath

Can someone tell me if I have something wrong with my formula or what I´m trying is just not something possible in sheets?

Comment: `IMPORTDATA` retrieves the data from the publicly shared URL. Unfortunately, in the current stage, `IMPORTDATA` cannot directly retrieve the file from the local PC. For example, when the CSV file is put in the publicly shared site, it can be retrieved with `IMPORTDATA`. When the CSV file is put in the storage which is required to authorize, Google Apps Script might be able to retrieve it. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried another way of importing the data. I sync the local file to Google Drive wich has the csv file, however I got a really different format when I import the csv from Drive to my spreadsheet.  Its something like a lot of random formulas and no csv information

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I sync the local file to Google Drive wich has the csv file, however I got a really different format when I import the csv from Drive to my spreadsheet. Its something like a lot of random formulas and no csv information`, I cannot imagine the detail of your issue. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? And, can you provide the detail method for correctly replicating your current issue?

Comment: Sure and thanks for the help. I will add some images and the spreadsheet link . https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A3Neas52UhmvEQ3QaaqV2VheAXDStj9M/view?usp=sharing (in that photo you will see how the csv is supposed to loook like. And in the spreadsheet you´ll see that is completely diferent. The formula is in cell A1 . This is the spreadsheet link. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ccLhl5F8_k6TiBAz8YB5Xmpeu7i0B1O2zn3nfnfH-SA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful and I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

When I saw your Spreadsheet, I found the following formula.

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://drive.google.com/file/d/###/view?usp=sharing")
```

In this case, even when the file is the CSV data, HTML is returned. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. In order to avoid this issue, how about the following patterns? I thought that one of the following 2 patterns might be able to be used for your situation.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the CSV data is loaded using the formula `IMPORTDATA`. For this, please do the following flow.

1. Publicly share the CSV file.
2. Put a formula of `=IMPORTDATA("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=###")`.

   - Please replace `###` to your file ID of CSV file.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the CSV data is loaded using Google Apps Script. Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set the file ID of your CSV file and run `myFunction`. By this, the CSV data is put to the sheet `Sheet1`. When you want to change the sheet, please modify `Sheet1`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const fileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID of CSV file on your Google Drive.
  const csv = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  const values = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### References:

- [parseCsv(csv)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)